# Is there a way to give color options in a form and that this color is also sent to the database?

Tags: html, css, database, forms, colors

The idea is that there are different buttons in that color and that they can then choose a color (no color picker). anyone any idea what input option I can user for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a color picker, then you should go with `input type=text` and set the value of that input to the color (either the name, hex value, or rgb value depending on however you want to store it in your database). The best way to do so is to get a JSON list of colors so you can simply loop over that list and render an input (or button) for every color.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add the hex value in a `data-` attribute. So once the user clicks on a button you can read its `data` attribute via jQuery or JavaScript and pass it on to the database...

example:

```
    <div id="color-btn-wrapper">
        <button data-choosen-color="000">Black</button>
        <button data-choosen-color="f00">Red</button>
        <button data-choosen-color="f60">Orange</button>
    </ul>
```

**Hint:** On page load you can also read this `data-choosen-color` attribute to apply the color for each button too. So you get 2 tasks done once and accurately.